# Ubuntu 12.04 isn't working with one of my crontab commands... any ideas?

Tags: 12.04, bash, cron

In my crontab file (`sudo crontab -e`) I have the following commands:

```
*/1 * * * * wget -q -O /dev/null http://help.mysite.com/inc/mail/hesk_pop3.php
0 7 * * * bash -c "/home/backup/backupscript.sh"
```

The first line executes and works correctly, but the second line isn't working for some reason. However, If I run the script through terminal (`./backupscript.sh`) it runs correctly.

The backupscript.sh file is owned by root:root and has 755 permissions.

Within that file is the following bit of code:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/mysqldump -u root -wordpresspassword wordpressusername | /bin/gzip > /home/backup/mysql/wordpress_`date +%m-%d-%Y_%T`.sql.gz
/usr/bin/mysqldump -u root -heskpassword heskusername | /bin/gzip > /home/backup/mysql/hesk_`date +%m-%d-%Y_%T`.sql.gz
/bin/tar cvzf /home/backup/wordpress/wordpress_`date +%m-%d-%Y_%T`.tar.gz /var/www/wordpress/
/bin/tar cvzf /home/backup/hesk/hesk_`date +%m-%d-%Y_%T`.tar.gz /var/www/hesk/
/usr/bin/s3cmd sync -r -P /home/backup/ s3://backups.mysite/
find /home/backup/ -mtime +7 -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

The script basically backups our MySQL databases and compresses them, backs up our apache sites and compresses them, copies those files to Amazon S3, and then performs a cleanup on the server.

What am I missing here? I've tried a number of things like switching from bash to shell but nothing I've done has worked yet.

Comment: Just to make sure: does `sudo bash -c "/home/backup/backupscript.sh"` work?

Comment: I'm not familiar with s3cmd but I would assume it requires access to your keyring for upload credentials. This is something that root cannot access if stored in your own keyring. That is just a shot in the dark, could you post the error message from the cron run?

Comment: @Gertjan - Yep, the script runs fine when I run that in terminal.

Comment: @SimonDeziel Yea, s3cmd stores the Amazon key and secret key in a configuration file. We set that up with "s3cmd -config" if I remember correctly. It's processing that command fine and copying the files to S3 as long as I run the script in terminal and not try to automate it using cron. How would I get the error message from cron run?

Comment: @KrisAnderson, you can see the cron generated messages if you have a working mailer. All cron job output will be emailed to root by default. Also, I noticed that 2 of your commands are not using full path (find and date). This cause problem as the PATH when cron execute a job is more limited.

Comment: @SimonDeziel - Thanks for the feedback. I updated the find command to /usr/bin/find and the date to /bin/date. I also found another post where someone mentioned they got this to work by editing (sudo nano /etc/crontab) instead of (sudo crontab -e) like I've been trying. I'm going to try your suggestion and this other cron file to see if this works.

Comment: I checked and /usr/bin and /bin are already part of the PATH even under cron so likely not your problem. The s3cmd uses a config file located in $HOME/.s3cfg. Maybe you'd want to override this to point the right home and not /root/.s3cfg

Comment: Also, why trying to run this as root if you said your own user could run it no problem? Why not simply add this to your user's crontab?

Comment: @SimonDeziel - Thanks Simon. I had been trying to run the script in another folder created in the home folder but that didn't work (likely a permissions issue). I moved the script and backup folder to my personal home directory and the cron job ran fine without root under my user account. Thanks again for the suggestion!

Comment: You could add `-x` to your script call. The script will print out every step it does. Usually you'll get it via mail. This may help to find the cause.

Answer (score 1):

General tips for debugging crontab:

1. catch the output.

   - Either redirect it to a file, e.g. `{ command1; command2; } &>/tmp/joboutput`
   - or ensure that the crond send output as email to your mailbox by setting `MAILTO=user@example.com` in your crontab.
2. The shell environment of process invoked by crontab differ from the environment started the same process in a terminal.
    
   Ensure that all necessary environment variables either specified inside the crontab.
3. **%** has a special meaning in the crontab (read carefully `man 5 crontab` :-)

> The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or % character, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell specified in the SHELL variable of the crontab file. Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless  escaped  with  backslash (),  will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first % will be sent to the command as standard input. There is no way to split a single command line onto multiple lines, like the shell's trailing "\".

Answer (score 1):

one workaround is to use shell script to do this:

```
for (( ; ;))
do
   sleep 86400
   wget -q -O http://help.mysite.com/inc/mail/hesk_pop3.php
   /bin/sh /home/backup/backupscript.sh
done
```

In above script, I have used `sleep 86400` (it's equivalent of one day in seconds). You can configure your interval accordingly.

If you want to run on some server/desktop by logging using ssh, then start/run this script as background process.